# Is there any way to access the excel file online using xlsxwriter in python?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to create and write to excel file using python. I am able to open the excel file only after the complete code has been executed with the last line being workbook.close().

If I want to view the excel file while python is writing data to the file, how can I do that?

Comment: "I want to view the excel file while python is writing data to the file" - that doesn't work. First of all, the close() call is probably where python actually writes the data to disk, and before that it's just in a memory buffer. Second, a half-written file would be invalid and excel would simply refuse to open it.

Comment: If your intention is to have a preview, you could create a smaller copy of your data first, e.g. top 100 rows and create a separate "preview" excel file first

Comment: is there any other package in python that allows to keep reading the excel file, if not xlsxwriter?